# Saving Knock out js Drop Down value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi i want to save the selected value of a drop down to the server , But every time it is returning same value not the updated value which i selected.

My kO:

```
      var stateModel = {
          CountriesList: ko.observableArray([]),
          StateId: ko.observable(),
          StateName: ko.observable('').extend({ required: true }),
          ShortName: ko.observable('').extend({ required: true }),
          IsActive: ko.observable(true),
          CountryId: ko.observable()



      var stateViewModel = function () {
          var self = this;
          self.StateModel = stateModel;
          self.CountriesList = ko.observableArray([]);
          self.StatesList = ko.observableArray([]);
          self.CountryId = ko.observable();
```

I am calling this Add State in a button click, But every time it is returing in args like:
**{"argBO":{"CountriesList":[],"StateName":"asdf","ShortName":"s","IsActive":true}}**

```
      self.AddState = function () {
              var args = JSON.stringify({ argBO: jQuery.parseJSON(ko.toJSON(self.StateModel)) });
              alert(args);
              ajax.Post("AddState.aspx/AddState", args, false).success(function (data) {

      };

  var vm = new stateViewModel();

          ajax.Get("AddCountry.aspx/getCountries", { IsActive: true }, false).success(function (data) {
              vm.CountriesList(data.d);
          });

          ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("divcountry"));


          ko.applyBindings(stateViewModel, document.getElementById("state_container"));

          var vm1 = new stateViewModel();
          ajax.Get("AddState.aspx/getStates", { IsActive: true }, false).success(function (data) {
              vm1.StatesList(data.d);
          });
```

Dropdown is in divcountry, and StateName,ShortName are in state_containerdiv..Actually i have dummy label in divCountry beside DropDown which is giving me correct selected value depending on the Dropdown selection...

```
        <div id="divcountry">          
             <select   data-bind="options: CountriesList,optionsText: 'CountryName',optionsValue:'CountryId',value:CountryId,optionsCaption: 'Select Country..'" style="width: 148px">
            </select>
            <label data-bind="text: CountryId"></label>
         </div>
```

Where i am wrong?? I have been searching online from 2days!! I would be thankfull !!

Comment: You may need to loop though data.d and do a vm.CountriesList.push to get the values in the observable array.

Comment: Is my observable not getting values here?? If it is then does does the dummy label showing Observable CountryId??

Comment: Try my approach and see

Comment: like this??for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) { vm.CountriesList.push(data.d[i]); }

Comment: Nothing has changed?? Shud i change my coutry id observable?

Answer (score 1):

i think if we you modify stateModel as class that may work for you,

```
  var stateModel = function(){
          CountriesList: [],
          StateId: '',
          StateName: '',
          ShortName: '',
          IsActive: true,
          CountryId: 0
}


      var stateViewModel = function () {
          var self = this;
          self.StateModel = new ko.observable(new stateModel());
          self.CountriesList = ko.observableArray([]);
          self.StatesList = ko.observableArray([]);
          self.CountryId = ko.observable();
          }
```

and change self.StateModel to self.StateModel()

Comment: Actually i am trying to save a form using ko, in which i used a drop down in div, and other text boxes in another table..First i am binding the drop down to some countries by ko.applybindings("viewmodel",doc..getelementbyid("divCountry"),,after this i want to save this country selected, with other text boxes values which are in parent element table. Can i do like this??

Answer (score 0):

I am again going to urge to take a proper amount of time and read through the knockoutjs documentation and get a good understanding of binding contexts amongst other things. Because even though you state that you understand binding-contexts, all you questions in the past days indicate otherwise. And then after that ask yourself the question why you are posting vm.StateModel in the first place.

`vm.CountryId` does not equal `vm.StateModel.CountryId`

Comment: I have been waiting for ur reply from 2 days,,U only seems to have good knowledge on ko....Actually the problem with me is this whole ko seems to be new to me!!! I referred your References and some other for the basics, but they are not giving me proper knowledge on this!!!

Comment: In the answer you told that why am posting vm.statemodel in first?? what you are asking about?? First i am binding my countries list to drop down by ko.applybindings(vm, document.getElementById("divcountry")); and then i am posting my statemodel bu ko.applyBindings(stateViewModel, document.getElementById("state_container"));